# Sending selected checkboxes (with jquery select all function) returns no array?

Tags: jquery, forms

I am trying to get all checkboxes checked with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#delmsg_all").click(function()               
        {
            var checked_status = this.checked;
            $("input[(name=delmsg[])]").each(function()
            {
                this.checked = checked_status;
            });
        });                 
    });

</script>
```

All checkboxes get checked.
form part:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="delmsg[]" value="<?php echo $aRows['pvID'];?>"/>
```

So far, so good, but.....

i expect an array with all checked values, but i dont get an array back?

code for checking what is sent by my form:

```
## Berichten verwijderen
// test op eigen berichten??
if(isset($_POST['todo']) AND $_POST['todo'] == 'verwijder_mijn_berichten')
{
    if(is_array($_POST['delmsg']))
        $aMeldingen[] = 'yessss';// shows text in jquery lightbox
    else
        $aErrors[] = 'test?'; // just used as testvalue
    foreach($_POST['delmsg'] AS $key => $value)
    {
        $aMeldingen[] = $key.' => '.$value;
        echo $key.' => '.$value;
    }

}
```

Problem:
when i use delmsg as name of the checkboxes, the jquery function works, all checkboxes become checked, but after submitting the form, no array is recognized.

when i use delmsg[] as name of my checkboxes, the jquery function does NOT check all the checkboxes, but the array is recognized well. (after i selected some checkboxes by hand)

Where does it go wrong with my thoughts?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Frankly, your question would be better of without the confusing code examples (keeping only the part that starts with 'Problem:').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little bit problematic to use brackets in name attribute. jQuery selector engine sizzle uses it for a different purpose, so it does not recognize it directly. You have to escape it twice like `\\[\\]`. ([From jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)) You can get your checkboxes like this: `$("input[name=delmsg\\[\\]]")`

If it's not important you can give same class to your checkboxes and then select them with class name;

**HTML/PHP**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="delmsg[]" class="delmsg" value="<?php echo $aRows['pvID'];?>"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#delmsg_all").click(function()               
    {
        $(".delmsg").prop('checked', this.checked);
    });                 
});
```

By the way, if you will not do something else in `each` iteration, you can set checked property with just one command; `.prop()`

If you don't want to use extra class, you may get checkboxes with `:checkbox` selector.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#delmsg_all").click(function()               
    {
        $(":checkbox").prop('checked', this.checked);
    });                 
});
```

Comment: Did not work, firebug erroro: $(".delmsg").prop is not a function
http://www.xxxxxx.nl/pagina.php?mod=ts_mijnteam
Line 488

Comment: It's related with your jQuery version. If it's < 1.6 then you should use `.attr()`, if it's >= 1.6 then `.prop()` is fine.